# Counting length of intersection of a list with pandas column of lists

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, intersection, set-intersection

I have a list of unique random integers and a dataframe with a column of lists, like below:

```
>>> panel
    [1, 10, 9, 5, 6]

>>> df
       col1 
    0  [1, 5]
    1  [2, 3, 4]
    2  [9, 10, 6]
```

The output I would like to have is the length of the overlapping between `panel` and each individual list in the dataframe:

```
>>> result
       col1        res
    0  [1, 5]      2
    1  [2, 3, 4]   0
    2  [9, 10, 6]  3
```

Currently, I am using the `apply` function, but I was wondering if there are faster ways, since I need to create a lot of panels and loop through this task for each panel.

```
# My version right now
def cntOverlap(panel, series):
    # Typically the lists inside df will be much shorter than panel, 
    # so I think the fastest way would be converting the panel into a set 
    # and loop through the lists within the dataframe

    return sum(1 if x in panel for x in series)
    #return len(np.setxor1d(list(panel), series))
    #return len(panel.difference(series))


for i, panel in enumerate(list_of_panels):
    panel = set(panel)
    df[f"panel_{i}"] = df["col1"].apply(lambda x: cntOverlap(panel, x))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Owing to the variable length data per row, we need to iterate (explicitly or implicitly i.e. under the hoods) staying within Python. But, we can optimize to a level where per iteration compute is minimized. Going with that philosophy, here's one with array-assignment and some masking -

```
# l is input list of unique random integers
s = df.col1
max_num = 10 # max number in df, if not known use : max(max(s))
map_ar = np.zeros(max_num+1, dtype=bool)
map_ar[l] = 1
df['res'] = [map_ar[v].sum() for v in s]
```

Alternatively with 2D array-assignment to further minimize per-iteration-compute -

```
map_ar = np.zeros((len(df),max_num+1), dtype=bool)
map_ar[:,l] = 1
for i,v in enumerate(s):
    map_ar[i,v] = 0
df['res'] = len(l)-map_ar.sum(1)
```

Comment: It works as I wanted, but the optimization with the 2D array does not work for me because of the memory allocation in numpy arrays. In any case thank you!

Comment: I just realized right now that `max(max(s))`does not return the biggest element in the column of lists, is that not the purpose of this line? I had to change it to `max(s.apply(lambda x: max(x))`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `explode` (available from pandas 0.25+) and `isin`:

```
df['col1'].explode().isin(panel).sum(level=0)
```

Output:

```
0    2.0
1    0.0
2    3.0
Name: col1, dtype: float64
```